# Immutable JS List size

Tags: reactjs, typescript, size, immutable.js, immutablelist

I don't get how Immutable JS List size will grown.

As in the example on official doc https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/push , pushing something in an immutable js List will automatically grown size.

In my code:

```
const list: List = List();
list.push(object);
console.log(list, list.size);
```

My output in consolle is:

```
(1) object
length: 1
___proto___: Array(0)

undefined
```

That is really different from the aspected output.
There is no size, if I use length in my code Typescript tell me that it doesn't exist "length" in List.
I use React with Typescript and Immutable.JS

Anybody has an idea of what happens?

Comment: the push method returns a new immutable list, that's the one you should be checking the size on, not the original one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Immutability means that operations do not change the original object but instead create a new one.

In your case the `push` method will return a **new** list with all the old elements and the new one you just added.

Your code should look something like this.

```js
const list: List = List();
const newList = list.push(object);
console.log(list, list.size);
console.log(newlist, newlist.size);
```

This should print a size of 0 for the `list` variable and a size of 1 for the `newList` variable.